# How can I write a file to a specific inode on an ext2 image?

Tags: filesystems, ext2

I have an ext2 image file, and I need to write a file to a specific inode within the image using command line utilities in Linux. I tried using debugfs but I couldn't find a way to write to a specific inode. Can someone provide guidance on how to write a file to a specific inode on an ext2 image using command line tools? Any insights, commands, or sample scripts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify your question.  Do you want to edit the contents of an existing inode or do you want to create a new inode with a specific inode number?  And you want to do this without mounting the filesystem?

Comment: I would like to create a new inode with a specific inode number and would like to do this without mounting the filesystem.

Comment: Presumably that new inode would be for a regular file and you would allocate some content to it? You'd likely also want to link it to at least one directory or otherwise it would be orphaned and linked to `lost+found` at the next fsck.